# Passing and parsing file matches

Tags: bash, arguments, wildcard, glob

I want to pass files that match some wildcard or regex.  Would it be acceptable to pass the filenames to the script in this way?

```
mse -s /media/hagbard/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/A*
```

The `-s` would be an option, but then `/media/hag/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/A*` would constitute a number of filenames, one after each other.

Currently I am parsing argumunts with the following, but have to take care of the `-s` option, so it does not capture just one value.
This could make sense, unless there are many files.  If there are too many files for args to handle, I need to be able to pass and interepret some form of wildcard or regex, which also requires an appropriate option and associated parsing scheme.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 IFSPREV="$IFS"
 IFS="="
 set -- $*

 IFS="$IFSPREV"  # Set original IFS

 local iarg=0
 local narg="$#"
 while (( narg > 0 )); do

   opt="$1"
   iarg=$(( iarg + 1 ))

   case $opt in
     ("-s"|"--src"|"--source")  src="$2"  ; shift 2 ;;
     ("-d"|"--dst"|"--destin")  dst="$2"  ; shift 2 ;;
     ("--")  shift 1 ; break ;;
     (-*)  printf '%s\n' "Unknown option: $1" ; shift 1 ;;
     (*) break ;;
   esac

 done

 for name in "$src"; do
   rsync -av --update "$src" "$dst"
 done
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of using one element, use a bash array.

```
srcs=()
...
printf "You passed filenames:\n"
printf "   %s\n" "${srcs[@]}"
```

There are many solutions. Preferably implement single flag and reading from zero separated file or just positional arguments.

1. Instead of adding one element, add them to an array.

   ```
   ("-s"|"--src"|"--source") srcs+=("$2"); shift 2 ;;
   ```

And require the user to add `-s` in front of every filename:

```
args=(); for i in /media/hagbard/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/A*; do args+=(-s "$i"); done
mse "${args[@]}"
```

2. Require the user to pass a globbing (or regex) expression and expand it on your side.

   ```
    # ex. find -name '*.txt'
    # or git ls-files '*.txt'
    # BAD code - does not handle whitespaces in filenames
    ("-g"|"--srcglob"|"--sourceglob") srcs+=($(compgen -G "$2")); shift 2 ;;
   ```

You would do, note quotes:

```
 ./mse '/media/hagbard/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/A*'
```

3. Allow the user to pass from file.

   ```
    # see rsync --from0 --from-file documentation of these flags
    (-0|--from0) mapfileargs=(-d '') ;;
    (--from-file) readarray -t "${mapfileargs[@]}" srcs < <(cat "$2"); ;;
    # see grep -z -Z -f flags documentation
   ```

You would do:

```
printf "%s\0" /media/hagbard/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/A* | ./mse --from0 --files-from=-
```

4. Provide all arguments as positional arguments after options.

```
   ("--")  shift 1 ; break ;;
    ...
done

srcs=("$@")
```

It's the simplest - just use:

```
./mse /media/hagbard/hc1/a1-chaos/amvib/A*
```